Mac-USB-iPhone sync of large number of Contacts fails. Why, and how to solve?
iCloud quit syncing my Contacts, and Apple Tier-2 Support guesses I might have exceeded one of their iCloud limits [https://support.apple.com/en-us/103188], such as having too many photos or too large of photos (they say there’s no way to know).
Apple suggested I sync via USB instead. Except that fails too.
I connect my iPhone to my MacBook Pro via USB cable, view the iPhone in Finder, click Info, check “Sync contacts”, click “Sync”, and Finder runs through 4 of 4 syncing steps to completion, but no contacts appear on the phone. If I toggle the “Replace” checkbox and sync, still nothing.
If I export a VCard of all cards except the first 1,000, I delete those, and I sync, then it works. Except then when I import a 1,000 more from a VCard export and sync, it fails.
I have searched the web for any documentation of a limit on how many cards can be synced via USB and found nothing. I have asked Apple, and they say they don’t know.
Any ideas on how to fix this? Or how otherwise to sync my 7,000 total contacts between Mac and iPhone?
